# Why does Chomsky find it surprising that languages are learnable?

Tags: chomsky, minimalism

From the Minimalist Program, Chapter 1 (20th Anniversary Edition, pg. 16):

> It has sometimes been argued that linguistic theory must meet the empirical condition that it account for the ease and rapidity of parsing. But parsing does not, in fact, have these properties…

> In general, it is not the case that language is readily usable or “designed for use.” ***The subparts that are used are usable, trivially***.

> There is no a priori reason to expect that the languages permitted by UG be attainable under normal circumstances.

> ***If proposals within the P&P approach are close to the mark, then it will follow that languages are in fact learnable, but that is an empirical discovery, and a rather surprising one.***

(edited and with my own omissions)

Why does Chomsky think UG would have evolved at all, if only to generate unlearnable languages?

What does he consider “attainable under normal circumstances” - environmental factors regarding availability of language “training” data, or the language itself being too complex for the human mind to grasp, or something?

Comment: That second quote just makes no sense to me at all. How could language possibly not be readily usable or designed for use?

Comment: you may start with this https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/27996/chapter-abstract/211719982?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: @AlexB. thank you, that’s right on point (Howard lasnik is the co-author of the chapter I quoted)

Comment: I wish there was an easy way to get any such article

Comment: @hmltn https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Argument-from-the-Poverty-of-the-Stimulus-Lasnik-Lidz/c7ddc641d448e945ebca43932a4d32827a621208

Comment: @AlexB. thank you, it’s invaluable so far and fascinating. There is some really hotly debated questions apparently about what kind of data children actually are exposed to. Pg. 20 “structure dependence and polar interrogatives” cites Pullum & Scholz refuting Chomsky’s POS claim, but then Lasnik et al claim their corpora were skewed. That would be fascinating given how I had come to see Pullum as the indefatigable rationalist against Chomsky’s dogmatism - but perhaps now the pendulum may swing back again, I do not know.

Comment: pg. 22: “one of the most informative approaches to separating the contribution of the learner from the contribution of the environment is to withhold certain kinds of experiences from the learner and to see what gets acquired... While experiments like these are unethical to conduct with human children (but see Feldman, Goldin-Meadow, and Gleitman 1978, Landau and Gleitman 1985, and Senghas and Coppola 2001 for some natural variants), we can recreate this kind of selective rearing experiment in the laboratory through the use of artificial languages.”

Comment: I specifically remember my intro to semantics professor saying this in 2014 when I asked if it turned out there was no “universal grammar”. He said something like “most of the most important experiments we could do in linguistics would be unethical”.

Answer (score 3):

Chomsky finds it surprising kids can learn languages for a couple reasons.

First, he believes all human languages follow some universal grammar rules built into our brains. But these rules could logically allow for tons of really complicated languages - even ones too wild for anyone to actually learn.

There's no reason to think the languages that evolved would just happen to be simple enough for kids to figure out. It could have been a mess! Second, children don't get perfect examples of language when they're learning. It's all mixed up, half-finished, with mistakes. It's amazing they can make sense of the disorder and get the grammar right.

It's like if I gave you a pile of jumbled lego pieces, only some assembly instructions, and you had to recreate a huge lego castle perfectly.

So Chomsky believes children have an innate universal grammar ability. But he finds it really surprising, almost unbelievable, that the complicated languages this allows are the same ones kids can actually learn based on the limited scraps of language they hear.

That's why he says language learning being possible at all is a lucky accident, not something he would have predicted from his theory. It just happened to work out, which is weird if you think about it. So in short, he finds it almost unbelievable that the grammar kids have built into their brains lines up so well with the messy complicated languages we speak.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Languages aren't subject to "natural selection" generally speaking, but in the particular example of a language that starts being used by adults but that children cannot learn, that language will die out as the adults who speak it die, and as such, it's extremely improbable that we'd be able to witness such a language, even if one or several had existed in the past. Their only fate can be death.

Comment: It seems you're suggesting a kind of 'cultural selection' happening with languages. Languages that can't be learned by children would indeed likely disappear over time, effectively being 'selected out'. This is a compelling counterpoint to Chomsky's surprise about children's ability to learn complex languages. But I am not Chomsky and do not advocate his view. I only tried to explain WHY he might think so.

Comment: I am not sure I believe in complicated languages. Also, he probably only speaks English. [still alive last time I looked].

Comment: I’m not sure about this answer, but I appreciate the attempt. I wonder if the key word is “learnable”, in that Chomsky is saying that it would be more expected for language to be fully innate with almost no external learning from the environment, but that there is some learning to a degree; possibly.